How to mock the Database (SQLModel + FastAPI)
I want to test my GraphQL endpoint. To do this, I have to mock the database.
from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import os


class Database:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.engine = None

    def connect(self) -> None:
        if not self.engine:
            self.engine = create_async_engine(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///db.sqlite")
            )
        else:
            raise ConnectionAbortedError("Database is already connected")

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def get_async_session(self):
        if not self.engine:
            raise ConnectionError("Database is not connected")

        async with AsyncSession(self.engine) as session:
            try:
                yield session
            finally:
                await session.close()

I've tried to mock create_engine in my test,
async def test_register_user_mutation(self, gql_schema: Schema, engine):
    with patch("sqlmodel.create_engine") as mock_create_engine:
        mock_create_engine.return_value = engine

in the app fixture
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def app() -> FastAPI:
    engine = create_engine(
        "sqlite://", connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}, poolclass=StaticPool
    )
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

    with patch("sqlmodel.create_engine") as mock_create_engine:
        mock_create_engine.return_value = engine

        from daytistics.main import app

        return app

and I've to mock the Session
async def test_register_user_mutation(self, gql_schema: Schema, engine):
        with patch("sqlmodel.Session", autospec=True) as mock_session_class:
            mock_session_class.return_value = Session(engine)

but each time it was written to the production database.
I don't if it's useful, but this is my app factory:
def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    dotenv.load_dotenv()
    app = FastAPI()

    register_dependencies()

    with container.sync_context() as ctx:
        db = ctx.resolve(Database)
        db.connect()

    graphql_router = create_graphql_router()
    app.include_router(graphql_router, prefix="/graphql")

    return app


app = create_app()

Update:
I've tried to use a monkeypatch and it did not work either:
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
async def mock_db(monkeypatch):
    test_engine = create_async_engine(
        "sqlite+aiosqlite:///:memory:",
        echo=False,
        future=True,
        connect_args={"check_same_thread": False},
    )

    async with test_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.create_all)

    def mock_connect(self):
        self.engine = test_engine

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def mock_get_async_session(self):
        async with AsyncSession(test_engine) as session:
            try:
                yield session
            finally:
                await session.close()

    monkeypatch.setattr(Database, "connect", mock_connect)
    monkeypatch.setattr(Database, "get_async_session", mock_get_async_session)

    return test_engine


Please, share a simple example of endpoint that uses db session. It's not clear from the code you've shared how you are passing session into your endpoint functions
